# How to search for certain name in XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml, search, xpath, nodes

I want to be able to go trough the each of the nodes in XML and when I find a certain **username** I want to read all the data from that node.

For example:

```
<Users>
   <User>
      <Username>admin</Username>
      <Server>10.x.x.x</Server>
   </User>
   <User>
      <Username>test</Username>
      <Server>11.x.x.x</Server>
   </User>
</Users>
```

I need to be able to find **Username=admin** and then get the **Server** from the same node.
I will be using a PHP and you can make example with saving in any two variables.

Comment: Check [DOMXPath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php). This allows you to do XPath queries on your document.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but I couldn't figure it out with these examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Xpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) and [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) , something like this should do the trick :

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($xml); // Your xml string
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$query = '//Users/User/Username[. = "admin"]'; // Looking for user admin
$entries = $xpath->query($query);

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    //Getting the "server" node value for "admin" user
    echo $entry->nextSibling->nextSibling->nodeValue; // Display 10.x.x.x
}
```

Comment: so if I have more than one sibling I can just user this line one more time? `echo $entry->nextSibling->nextSibling->nodeValue;` How to insert an PHP variable instead of "admin"

Comment: Take five seconds to read the PHP doc about DomDocument and you will find the load() method which let you load a file instead of a string ...

Comment: Can you please tell me one thing. When I want to read the next sibling in that XML just image that I have one more node bellow "SERVER" name. How can I do that? I am using : `foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    //Getting the "server" node value
    $server=$entry->nextSibling->nextSibling->nodeValue; 
 $image=$entry->nextSibling->nextSibling->nextSibling->nodeValue; 
}` and its not giving me a last node value only the first one

Answer (score 1):

This variant works

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadXML(file_get_contents('xpath.xml'));
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$query = '//Users/User/Username[text()="admin"]/following-sibling::Server';
echo $xpath->query($query)->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

try something along these lines:

```
$input = '<Users>
   <User>
      <Username>admin</Username>
      <Server>10.x.x.x</Server>
   </User>
   <User>
      <Username>test</Username>
      <Server>11.x.x.x</Server>
   </User>
</Users>';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($input);

$result = $xml->xpath('/Users/User[Username="admin"]');
// Process $result to your liking..
```

For simplicity I've used SimpleXMLElement. If you require more powerful tools, have a look at DomDocument and [DOMXPath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).

More details regarding SimpleXML [Xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php).

Comment: maybe you didn't understood me correctly. I need to iterate trough each of the `<User></User>` nodes so I can find which one has for example username `admin` and if that user exists then read `server` name

Comment: I understood what you meant, the Xpath is updated to fit what you were after.